# PHP PDO Prepared Statements with IN and WHERE Operators

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO (coming from mysqli) and I have been searching for hours and cannot seem to figure out how to combine the WHERE and IN operators with PDO prepared statements.

Simple WHERE (Works Fine):

```
$value1 = 'val1';
$value2 = 'val2';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE val1 = ? AND val2 = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value2);
$stmt->execute();
```

IN Statement (Works Fine)

```
$myArr = ['NY', 'PARIS', 'ROME'];
$q  = str_repeat('?,', count($myArr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE cities IN ($q)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($myArr);
```

Combining (Not Working):

```
$value1 = 'val1';
$myArr = ['NY', 'PARIS', 'ROME'];
$q  = str_repeat('?,', count($myArr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column = ? AND cities IN ($q)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);
$stmt->execute($myArr);
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What is `$value1` I dont see it defined and why is `$myArr` in the execute

Comment: Use `→bindParam` **or** `→execute(ARRAY)`, not both.

Comment: What is `column = ?` supposed to be?

Comment: `$value1` is just for display purposes, it is defined earlier in the code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly My understanding is with the IN operator, the `$q` var will be filled in with ? based on the count of the array, I just need to specify a WHERE along with an IN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason this is not working is because you are using both

`$stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);
$stmt->execute($myArr);`

To use an array and make it work do as follows:

`prepare($sql);`

`execute($myArr);`

In `$myArr` you should include whatever `columns = ?` is supposed to be, you can add this to the beginning of the array using `array_unshift()` like this `array_unshift($myArr, 'X');`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

After calling `array_unshift()` the variable `$myArr` will have the values as follows:

```
[myArr] => Array
        (
            [0] => X
            [1] => NY
            [2] => PARIS
            [3] => ROME
        )
```

Now you can call the PDO statements correctly:

```
prepare($sql);
execute($myArr);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for.  Makes perfect sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: @cableguy no problem. happy coding!